# Modify the last letters of words?

Tags: c#, string, input, char

I need to code a program, which changes the last two (or just the last) letter(s) of the inputted word because of some weird grammar rules of the Lithuanian language.

For example, my name is Kazys.
I want a code which could change the last two letters (ys) to another letter (y).
So when a person inputs

Kazys

The output would be

Hello, Kazy.

If a person inputs Balys, the code should change the name to Baly and print it.

I am just a beginner in C#. So, I don't even know some of the basic functions.
Any help is very appreciated!!

P.S. For those who wonder, why do I need this, I can tell you that it's a thing in Lithuanian grammar which requires to change the end of the word if you are addressing somebody.

Comment: I think it's very simple, you just need to know that strings are very similar to arrays. How you can use that fact in c# is what I don't know and I am not interested in c# at all. But for sure,  it will be something as simple as overwriting the last character or, changing the length of the string. So my advice is, read all you can about [Strings in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/)

Comment: I think you will have to hard-code all the changes that you want. Loop through the input words and find the last two letters. Then check if they need to be changed or not, proceed accordingly. Then again check if any changes are required in the last letter. I don't speak Lithuanian language, so I am not sure how many such rules are there or how exactly they work

Comment: @Ank if there is a rule, then this is not only unnecessary but also, a very bad thing to do. Specially if you don't know or understand the cost of searching an array of strings (*low level*) and can't think of a faster algorithm for doing such a thing.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi well I am guessing there will be many rules which apply in different conditions. So any way you will have to search through strings to find which rules apply to which strings and act accordingly.

Comment: I think what you are saying is that you want to apply an ending-replacement function with a potential ending and replacement, repeating until you've done one replacement. To test and apply a replacement, you'd want to see if the string ends with the ending and if so return a substring of the length of the name minus the length of the ending appended by the replacement. Hint: the words are pretty much translatable into C#.

Comment: @Ank you are right, in that case it would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an extension class that applies the rules stored in a dictionary easy enough. Complicated rules could make Regex a better option, but if simple string replacement, a case insensitive dictionary could be better to avoid checking every possible rule every time.

```
public static class LanguageExtensions
{

    // Define case insentive dictionary
    public static Dictionary<string, string> Rules = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        // List rules here
        { "ys", "y"},
    };

    public static string ApplyRules(this string input)
    {
        string suffix;
        if (input != null && input.Length > 2 && Rules.TryGetValue(input.Substring(input.Length - 2, 2), out suffix))
            return input.Remove(input.Length - 2) + suffix;
        else
            return input;
    }
}
```

Then, you just have to call the extension method:

```
Console.WriteLine("Kazys".ApplyRules()); // "Kazy"
```

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, think language rules like this are why regular expressions exist.  It allows you to easily make rules with look-aheads, look-behinds, etc., to make sure that the word is only changed if it fits a certain structure.  For your example case, it should be as easy as:

```
var firstName = "Kazys";
var formattedFirstName = Regex.Replace(firstName, @"ys$", "y");
```

The $ at the end of the string means that it will only change "ys" to "y" when "ys" are the last two letters in a string.

Regular Expressions can get much more complicated and many people don't like them.  However, I find them to be concise and clear most of the time.

Comment: So long as the rules are complicated enough to make it worthwhile, definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal working sample of what you might be after.
You seem to have complex requirements to code but, this is the basic concepts of replacing string(s) within a string.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ChangeLastChar_46223845
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TextBox txtbx_input = new TextBox();
        TextBox txtbx_result = new TextBox();
        Button btn = new Button();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddOurStuffToTheForm();

            PutDefaultWordInInputBox();
        }

        private void PutDefaultWordInInputBox()
        {
            txtbx_input.Text = "Krazys";
        }

        private void AddOurStuffToTheForm()
        {
            txtbx_input.Location = new Point(5, 5);
            btn.Location = new Point(5, txtbx_input.Location.Y + txtbx_input.Height + 5);
            txtbx_result.Location = new Point(5, btn.Location.Y + btn.Height + 5);

            btn.Text = "Substring";
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;

            this.Controls.Add(txtbx_input);
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
            this.Controls.Add(txtbx_result);

        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbx_input.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbx_input.Text))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (txtbx_input.Text.EndsWith("ys"))
            {
                txtbx_result.Text = "Hello " + txtbx_input.Text.Substring(0, txtbx_input.Text.Length - 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```